# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.joda.time.DateTime

Tags: android, gradle, jodatime

Getting this error when starting the app on android 4.3 API 18.

There are no compilation errors, and library is added in build.gradle

```
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.2'
```

On android api 23 works with no problems, but on this device the app crashes on start.

Any idea why?
( already tried to clean, rebuild, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem.

I put in **build.gradle**

```
    multiDexEnabled true
```

so I had to make my custom Application extend [MultiDexApplication](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html)

Comment: Please mark your answer as the correct one so it can help others in future searchs ;)

Comment: this solution worked for me...for 2 weeks, now I'm experiencing the same issue as previously

Comment: Under which build.gradle section does this line go?

Comment: @BareMetalCoder 
`
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
        ...
    }`