# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: at net.a.a.a.a.a (JodaTimeAndroid.java:39)

Tags: android, jodatime, android-jodatime

I have error reports on 18-19 API level:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
  at net.a.a.a.a.a (JodaTimeAndroid.java:39)
  at io.apptitude.premiumparking.App.initJodaTime (App.java:131)
  at io.apptitude.premiumparking.App.onCreate (App.java:73)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1014)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4747)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1343)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:136)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5584)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1268)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1084)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
```

Joda version: `net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.2`

Maybe it's answer help me: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.joda.time.DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698452/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-joda-time-datetime)

I could not reproduce myself, but this bug is in the fabric. 

Can help fix this? Thanks

Comment: What is the code that triggered this?

Comment: @Dragonthoughts Open application

Comment: I found my mistake. I exceeds the 64k limit for DEX files. Excuse for troubling